# Textbook recommendation for discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want a good textbook covering elemenents of discrete mathematics Average level.Im a mathematics undergraduate so i dont want it to be towards Computer science that much.Interested in combinatorics and graph theory .But also covering enumeration and other stuff.One book i found is [https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Discrete-Mathematics-C-Liu/dp/0071005447](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071005447) .

Comment: I think the book you have found is one of the best choices. There is also a greek translation available at bookstores.

Comment: "Concrete Mathematics" provide some practical methods.

Comment: Ken Rosen's Discrete math book is thorough and Ken writes good explanations.  The book has a phenomenal amount of exercises, which I think is its chief feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a math major I strongly recommend Edward A. Scheinerman, [*Mathematics: A Discrete Introduction*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0840049420); it’s well written, and it’s definitely aimed at math majors, not computer science majors. The book by Kenneth Rosen is exhaustive, but it’s aimed more at computer science majors and is not, in my opinion, all that well written; much the same goes for the one by Richard Johnsonbaugh. Susanna S. Epp, [*Discrete Mathematics with Applications*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495391328), is well written and does a decent job of targeting both math majors and computer science majors and is probably a little easier than the Scheinerman for someone who is encountering abstract mathematics and proofs for the first time.

Comment: @BrianMScott: Nice references! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The Book of Proof is a free PDF that is fairly good and easy to read, lots of examples. 'Discrete Mathematics with Graph Theory' By Goodaire and Parmenter may have what you're looking for and is decent, however, I feel it's too much of a 'light read' and the authors' humour is questionable. But there are lots of examples and practice problems with worked solutions.